# Alternatives for datagridview,msflexgrid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, msflexgrid

For storing data in a grid i can use datagridview or msflexgrid. But is there any other object is there which can be used as an alternative for this.

Comment: We need to know the target platform: ASP, WPF, Winform, etc. What you are up to and why you need an alternative would help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using VSFlexgrid it is also the same with the msflexgrid and data grid but they have different features. you can look at here. [VSFlexGrid](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/VSFlexGridPro/)